# Java Program Runs in One Machine and not on Another

Tags: java, runtime

I'm studying Java and I just wrote a program that turns CME quotes of soybeans, wheat or corn to "price per 60kg bag" in BRL(Brazilian Currency). I used JSmooth to wrap it and it runs perfectly on my machine. I tried sending it to my wife's PC in a Zip file and I also tried to execute it from the command line directly calling the Main class. In both cases, the program goes until the part where it asks the USD/BRL quote and after one enters it and presses "Enter", the program shows an aparent Runtime error:

Options: soybean / wheat / corn

Type name of commodity(lowercase):

soybean

Type current exchange rate(USD/BRL):

3.11

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
        at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.Scanner.next(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.Scanner.nextDouble(Unknown Source)
        at PriceCME.getExchange_Rate(PriceCME.java:26)
        at PriceCMEExecute.main(PriceCMEExecute.java:8)
```

I thought that maybe the version of Java on her pc was outdated, so I removed all previous versions, installed the JDK 111 and tried to run it again.
The same issue happened.
I then tried to recompile the .java files on her PC and there was no compile time error. When I tried to execute it, again the same issue.
The code is the following:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class PriceCME {
    private String nameOfCommodity;
    private final double BUSHEL_SOY_WHEAT = 27.2155;
    private final double BUSHEL_CORN = 25.4012;
    private final int KGPERSACA = 60;
    private double quote;
    private double exchRate;
    private double pricePerSaca;

        public void getNameOfComodity()
    {
        System.out.println("Options: soybean / wheat / corn");
        System.out.print("Type name of commodity(lowercase): ");
        System.out.println();
        Scanner commodity = new Scanner(System.in);
        nameOfCommodity = commodity.next();
    }

    public void getExchange_Rate()
    {
        System.out.print("Type current exchange rate(USD/BRL): ");
        System.out.println();
        Scanner exchangeRate = new Scanner(System.in);
        exchRate = exchangeRate.nextDouble();
    }

    public void getQuote()
    {
        System.out.println("Source for quotes: 
    http://www.cmegroup.com/trading/agricultural/");
        System.out.print("Type quote of commodity on CME: ");
        System.out.println();
        Scanner getQuote = new Scanner(System.in);
        quote = getQuote.nextDouble();
    }

    public void CalculatePricePerSaca()
    {
        switch(nameOfCommodity)
        {
            case "soybean":
            pricePerSaca = (((quote * KGPERSACA) / 100) / 
            BUSHEL_SOY_WHEAT) * exchRate;
            break;

            case "wheat":
            pricePerSaca = (((quote * KGPERSACA) / 100) /
            BUSHEL_SOY_WHEAT) * exchRate;
            break;

            case "corn":
            pricePerSaca = (((quote * KGPERSACA) / 100) /
            BUSHEL_CORN) * exchRate;
            break;
        }
    }

    public void getPricePerSaca()
    {
        System.out.printf("The price of %s \"Por Saca\" is:\nR$ %.2f ",
        nameOfCommodity, pricePerSaca);
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Type \"false\" to exit.");
        Scanner end = new Scanner(System.in);
        boolean theEnd = end.hasNext();
    }

    }

  public class PriceCMEExecute {

    public static void main(String[] args)

    {
        PriceCME myPriceCME = new PriceCME();
        myPriceCME.getNameOfComodity();
        myPriceCME.getExchange_Rate();
        myPriceCME.getQuote();
        myPriceCME.CalculatePricePerSaca();
        myPriceCME.getPricePerSaca();

    }
}
```

How can this be happening? Would it be a problem on the JVM on her machine?

Comment: Maybe they have another java version installed that interferes with the JDK. Is the other computer on linux?

Comment: I tried to do it on her Windows, but she does also have linux installed on her machine. But as I stated on the question, I checked for other java versions on her PC, removed the older ones and updated everything. And she doesn´t have java installed on her linux.

Comment: Would def try: 1. using one scanner and/or closing scanner after using it/them. 2. use locale, e.g. `Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in).useLocale(Locale.US);`

Comment: Some linux distros come with some java runtime that isn't JDK, anyway since it's on windows, maybe the problem is with the IDE? Try to compile a simple hello world from the cmd.

Comment: I see you're using IDEA, maybe you didn't set up JDK in it.

Comment: See the [javadoc for the Scanner class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextDouble()) which states "This method will throw InputMismatchException if the next token cannot be translated into a valid double value." So I would think @NickBell is probably correct that it's a locale issue because it doesn't seem to recognize 3.11 as a valid double value.

Comment: It worked! At first, it didn't because I put  Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in).useLocale(Locale.US);
and it compiled and ran in the IntellijIDEA, but when I tried the same thing in my other notepad++ file with the same code and tried to compile it with javac, it gave me an error, saying that "it could no find the (Locale.US) symbol". I decided to try to import the whole java.util class with java.util.* and tried again. This time it finally worked! Thank you!